# Unable to handle two text fields inside a list View builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

for ease, I've created a DartPad for you to try out.

I would like a simple list view with two text fields where users can add or delete items. The entered data is stored as a Map.

When I click on the 'Add New' button, it should create a new list tile. However, when I attempt to delete any item, it seems to delete a different list item. Another issue is that when I add a new item for the second time, the first item I created gets overridden with a blank text field. Could you please check this?

[DART PAD](https://dartpad.dev/?id=266c14e21ee809f74627279a328da1f4)

This is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Shift List'),
        ),
        body: ShiftList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShiftList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShiftListState createState() => _ShiftListState();
}

class _ShiftListState extends State<ShiftList> {
  Map<String, String> shifts = {
    '1': 'Morning',
    '2': 'Afternoon',
    '3': 'Night',
  };

  void addShift() {
    setState(() {
      String newKey = '';
      shifts[newKey] = '';
    });
  }

  void deleteShift(String key) {
    setState(() {
      shifts.remove(key);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: shifts.keys.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String key = shifts.keys.elementAt(index);
              String value = shifts[key]!;

              final keyController = TextEditingController(text: key);
              final valueController = TextEditingController(text: value);

              return ListTile(
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: keyController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: valueController,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  onPressed: () {
                    deleteShift(keyController.text);
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            addShift();
          },
          child: Text('Add Shift'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The Issue**

---

The main issue here is the code does **not have** the capability to **transform/change** the value assigned to the **blank string** key into a **non-blank string**.

Every time you call `void addShift` you are assuming that the last time you called it the "**temporary**" **blank-string** entry content/data was already move/update to something like `shifts['4'] = '';` *(4 here because you start with 3 items)* BUT your code never move/update the **blank string** entry.

**The Solution**

---

To resolve this issue you would need to extend the `TextEditingController keyController` to being able to perform a a key swap on `shifts`:

```dart
// Inside of your ListView.builder's itemBuilder
final keyController = TextEditingController(text: key);
final valueController = TextEditingController(text: value);
if (key == "") {
  keyController.addListener(() {
    shifts[keyController.text] = "${valueController.text}";
  });
  valueController.addListener(() {
    shifts[keyController.text] = "${valueController.text}";
  });
}
```

That will fix the insertion issue and the deletion issue as well.

**Notes**

---

I would advice you to change `shifts` from `Map<String, String>` to `List<Set<String>>. The` List<>`will automatically make your code avoid this extra work of swapping data between "indexes" with the`.add` function.

If you're worried about duplicated "number labels" for the shifts you might as well change to `List<String>` and use the built-in index. To rearrange the indexes you would replace `ListView` with `ReorderableListView`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html

Answer (score 1):

**The issue lies in your addShift() function.** You are creating an empty key each time with an empty value but you are not updating the hashmap with the new values from the textControllers. Since the map cannot have duplicate keys, whenever u press the add button again, it sees that the previously added key was empty as well so it will just override it as you are again creating just an empty key again instead of creating a unique key. On your UI you are adding the values to your tile widget but the inside the map it has that same empty entry.

You can do a few things to fix this.

1. Either you can generate keys in order whenever a tile is created so you can first pass them and just update the values.
2. Create a popup whenever u press to add a button that takes the key and actual value, and then update your hashmap with those so the ListView builder can update and show it. You should not create unnecessary empty entries in the hashmap when the user has not finished adding the data first.

Something like this:

```
//Get values from the popup and then pass them to the function to update the map
  void addShift(String key, String value) {
    setState(() {
      shifts[key] = value;
    });
  }
```

Also, your delete functions seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i realised there was a add button  missing in my listtile, added it and implement the functionality to update the map as well, This is the final code, The add button is supposed to add a new list tile with empty values and it is upto the users to add it manually.

```dart
class ShiftList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShiftListState createState() => _ShiftListState();
}

class _ShiftListState extends State<ShiftList> {
  Map<String, String> shifts = {
    '1': 'Morning',
    '2': 'Afternoon',
    '3': 'Night',
  };

  void addShift() {
    setState(() {
      String newKey = '';
      shifts[newKey] = '';
    });
  }

  void deleteShift(String key) {
    setState(() {
      shifts.remove(key);
    });
  }

  void updateShift(String oldKey, String newKey, String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      shifts.remove(oldKey);
      shifts[newKey] = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: shifts.keys.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String key = shifts.keys.elementAt(index);
              String value = shifts[key]!;

              final keyController = TextEditingController(text: key);
              final valueController = TextEditingController(text: value);

              return ListTile(
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: keyController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: valueController,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () {
                        updateShift(
                            key, keyController.text, valueController.text);
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () {
                        deleteShift(keyController.text);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            addShift();
          },
          child: const Text('Add Shift'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code that implement the model instead of Map, that make code more easier.

EDIT :
Add link to DartPad to run and test :
Link : https://dartpad.dev/?id=6893ec8338eac294af2b30ad398ac016

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Shift List'),
          ),
          body: ShiftList(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  /// ADD THIS MODEL
  class Shift {
    String? key;
    String? value;

    Shift({this.key, this.value});
  }

  class ShiftList extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<ShiftList> createState() => _ShiftListState();
  }

  class _ShiftListState extends State<ShiftList> {

    /// REMOVING MAP OF SHIFTS
  //   Map<String, String> shifts = {
  //     '1': 'Morning',
  //     '2': 'Afternoon',
  //     '3': 'Night',
  //   };


    /// CREATING LIST OF SHIFT MODEL
    List<Shift> shifts = [
      Shift(key: "1", value: "Morning"),
      Shift(key: "2", value: "Afternoon"),
      Shift(key: "3", value: "Evening"),
    ];

    void addShift() {
      setState(() {
        /// ADD SHIFT MODEL TO LIST OF SHIFTS
        shifts.add(Shift(key: "", value: ""));
      });
    }

    void deleteShift(int index) {
      setState(() {
        /// REMOVING SHIFT FROM LIST BASED ON INDEX
        shifts.removeAt(index);
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: shifts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  //               String key = shifts.keys.elementAt(index);
  //               String value = shifts[key]!;

      
          final keyController = TextEditingController(text: shifts[index].key);
          final valueController = TextEditingController(text: shifts[index].value);

          return ListTile(
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(                  
                    controller: keyController,
                    
                    /// ADD THIS FUNCTION TO SAVE OUR DATA
                    onTapOutside: (value) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      shifts[index].key = keyController.text;
                      setState((){});
                    }
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: valueController,
                    
                    /// THIS FUNCTION TO SAVE OUR DATA 
                    onTapOutside: (value) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      shifts[index].value = valueController.text;
                      setState((){});
                    }
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                deleteShift(index);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        addShift();
      },
      child: const Text('Add Shift'),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```